# How to output loading message as NSURL retrieves URL's html?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

I am using Swift's NSURL function to retrieve HTML output from a PHP script that interacts with a MySQL database with variables passed with POST and secured with an SSL certificate.

Everything is all fine and great except for the occasional prolonged loading which resulting in a blank table view. Is there any way to run a function while I am waiting for the response string? I am completely in the dark on this one.

Here is the code I am using:

```
let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.casacorazon.org/ios.html")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        if error != nil {
             print("Error: \(error)")
        } 
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.testLabel.text = "\(responseString!)"
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can add a UIActivityIndicatorView to display a loading symbol. And any code you place after `task.resume()` will run while the network call is happening. Depending if you're already on the main thread or not, you might need an additional dispatch block after it (the same way you do it in your completion callback):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // make your UIActivityIndicator visible here
}
```